# access ui from another class in android

Tags: android, user-interface

```
public class UploadToServer extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_to_server);

    uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);

      up= new Upload(this);

     uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
          @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

             dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "", "Uploading file...",     true);

              new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                                }
                            });                      

                      up.uploadFile(uploadFilePath);


                    }
                  }).start();        
            }



        });
```

i need to access this class ui from another class called UPLOAD.ineed to access dialog in the above class and dispaly a toast .  how can i do this.plz help me

```
        public class Upload   {       
        public Upload(UploadToServer context) {
    context=context;}
            context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {public void run() {
                            String msg = "yes";

                            context.messageText.setText(msg);
                           Toast.makeText(context, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                         });                                                                                         }
```

that is what i tried .is that ok.all i want to do is print a Toast.but when i tru this i get NULPOINT  exception

Comment: Your other class is an activity ?

Comment: other class is java class.not activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an instance of Activity to the other class, and from there, using that activity instance you can call a showMyToast() method in the original activity.

```
class MyActivity extends Activity{

// activity methods etc..

public void showMyToast(String message){
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // write code to show toast
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });


}

class MyOtherClass{
MyActivity myActivity;

MyOtherClass(MyActivity myActivity){
       this.myActivity=myActivity;

}

// To call the showMyToast() of Activiy do like this:
// myActivity.showMyToast("This is a toast");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you can just pass references of your ui elements to your java class ? With the constructor or with a setter.

Exemple :  up= new Upload(this, uploadButton, messageText);

and then do the updates in your object

Answer (score 0):

First you should pass an instance of your activity context to your non-activity class. You can access ui components using this context. Then you can implement this

```
yourContextObject.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run()
    {
        Toast.makeText(yourContextObject, "some text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: when i try  it i get following error.The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}

Comment: Yes, this is just and example. You should write a context object there.